# How to get the file path from a device acting as a usb mass storage in android

Tags: android, usb, filepath, usb-otg

I am trying to get filenames(and also the filepath), from a Garmin device which acts as a usb mass storage. Connecting the device to the computer, the filepath is G:\Garmin. Connecting that to the android tablet using OTG and Explorer(i have check the app setting - the package name is : com.android.rk), the filepath is USB/Garmin. Using ES File Explorer, I have seen that the file path is mnt/usb_storage/Garmin. So in the code, as I am trying to parse the system.xml from the file path usb_storage/Garmin, I have put the filepath like this:

```
String file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "mnt/usb_storage/Garmin/system.xml";
```

When I run the app, it crashes, meaning that it cannot find the file **system.xml**. Is it right that I use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() when I'm looking for the file in a usb device connected via OTG? Can you please point me to what should be done? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, you are actually pointing your sd card or internal storage (depending on which is set as current) and **under that** you are looking for the device mount point.

But mount points in Unix are seen at the root level.
Therefore, try directly `/mnt/usb_storage/Garmin/system.xml`, instead.

Comment: Thank you, I will be accepting this as soon as I can since you were the first one who said it via comment. Again, thanks ^_^

Answer (score 2):

```
String file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "mnt/usb_storage/Garmin/system.xml";
```

You mean:

```
String fileName = "/mnt/usb_storage/Garmin/system.xml";
```

That's all. Note tne /mnt/... so NOT mnt/...

Comment: Man.. you are so quick ;-).

Comment: But you two are very great. Thank you so much