# Get absolute path of the storage connected via OTG

Tags: android

Absolute path of storage connected via OTG in Android,

I have tried using storage access framework i can get the content uri of the directory selected but i couldn't convert to absolute file:// path.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE

I need to store the absolute file path to scan the directories when the app is opened or when user access the folders.

As explained in SO [How to get the file path from a device acting as a usb mass storage in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297714/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-a-device-acting-as-a-usb-mass-storage-in-android)

this does provide the natively mounted otg storage devices, Samsung device natively mount the storage device where you can get the absolute path, but other device its not mounting natively,

I have tried out with 
        String sdcard_path = System.getenv("SECONDARY_STORAGE"); it won't provide the usb mounted path.

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() provides the internal mounted device path 
/storage/emulated/0/
/sdcard/

not the otg mounted storages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the file path from a device acting as a usb mass storage in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30297714/how-to-get-the-file-path-from-a-device-acting-as-a-usb-mass-storage-in-android)

Comment: @DrMido i have tried using 

Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() this provides the internal storage of the device, not the otg mounted storage

Comment: Did you read the whole answer? he said "But mount points in Unix are seen at the root level.
Therefore, try directly /mnt/usb_storage/Garmin/system.xml, instead."

Comment: @DrMido, how can i get Gramin in /mnt/usb_storage/Garmin, can you please help me in that

Comment: check this to get all storage drives
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51283579/9821661